# Finding the Rightmost occurrence of a string

Tags: java, string, algorithm, recursion, methods

I am writing a recursive algorithm to find the rightmost occurrence of the word "yes" in a list of characters.

```
public class Question7 {


    public static int where(char[] A, String s, int i) {
        // A recursive function where()
        // Return the location of rightmost occurence of a given string s in a given array A
        // Complete the where function
        // You may want to add more parameters to the where function
        s = "yes";
        where(A, s, A.length);
        if (A.length < 3) {
            return -1;
        } else if (A.length == 3) {
            if (A[i - 2] == s.charAt(0) && A[i - 1] == s.charAt(1) && A[i] == s.charAt(2)) {
                return i - 2;
            } else {
                return -1;
            }
        } else {
            if (A[i - 2] == s.charAt(0) && A[i - 1] == s.charAt(1) && A[i] == s.charAt(2)) {
                return i - 2;
            } else {
                return where(A, s, i - 1);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] givenarray = {'o', 't', 'z', 'y', 'e', 's', 'v', 'g', 'r', 'a', 'y', 'e', 's'};

        // Test your method
        System.out.println("The rightmost occurence of 'yes' in the given array is at index " + where());
        // Your method should return 10
   }

}
```

My problem is at the bottom when calling the method. Should I use specific parameters or ones that aren't specific? For example: where(givenarray, "yes", givenarray.length) or just (char[] A, String s, int i)? I have never been very good at calling methods with parameters so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Look into recursion (https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~15110-s13/Unit05PtA-handout.pdf) . You are missing base case here. Make sure when you are calling the recursive function again, you are passing a smaller problem to solve.

Comment: Do you need to use recursions? 
For this specific problem converting the char Array to a String and using lastIndexOf gives you what you need without overcomplicating things.

Comment: @trappski I do need to use recursion.

Comment: @ajc I thought the base cases were the if length< 3 and if length ==3. I also believe I am calling the recursive function with a smaller problem since I return the where method starting at one less than the previous i.

Comment: You are calling the `where(..)` method before your base case. Can you guess what will happen because of that?

Comment: At the bottom, you will presumably want to call `where` like `where(givenarray, "yes", 0)`. The recursive implementation should have a base case like `if (i + s.length() >= A.length) return -1` to handle the case where the remaining array is too small to possibly hold the search string. Then, call `where(A, s, i+1)` and return that if it's greater than -1; otherwise, if `A` contains `s` starting at position `i`, return `i`; else, return -1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to understand what you want to return.

-- So here you have to get the index of the last occurrence of a word. What to do? Lets capture it. There are many ways to do it. One way is -

```
    public class Question7 {
        public static int lastFoundIndex = -1;
        ..
    }
```

Second, how to initiate the process?

```
    public static void main(String... args) {
        char[] givenArray = {'o', 't', 'z', 'y', 'e', 's', 'v', 'g', 'r', 'a', 'y', 'e', 's'};

        // this is the initializing function, where you pass 2 params
        // The array and Index from where you want to start looking.  
        where(givenArray, 0);  
        System.out.println("The rightmost occurence of 'yes' in the given array is at index "+ lastFoundIndex);
    }
```

Next, lets see how the `where(..)` function will be like.

```
    public static void where(char[] arr, int startIndex) {
        // this is the base case. First statement. 
        // Basically for testing, if the array is empty or we reached at the end of the execution (we'll reach there soon)
        if(startIndex >= arr.length) {
            return;
        }

        // Now we check if we have the word 'yes', if so - save the lastFoundIndex. and call where function and tell it to look starting from currentIndex + 3 place.  
        if(arr[startIndex] == 'y' && startIndex + 2 < arr.length) {
            if(arr[startIndex + 1] == 'e' && arr[startIndex + 2] == 's') {
                lastFoundIndex = startIndex;
                where(arr, startIndex+3);
            }
        }

        // if we dont find the character y, then just go on with next char.  
        where(arr, startIndex+1);
    }
```

Comment: Oh I see where I went wrong. Yes I was referencing the index all wrong. I appreciate your help!!